# Optional related paths with neo4j and cypher on a more complex MATCH statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query which is going over a graph of companies, groups, watchlists and members. See the [gist of dummy data in geoff format](https://gist.github.com/Jmaharman/534ee95e807aa193faf2) for the data in the database. I've also setup a [console neo4j](http://console.neo4j.org/r/vtrcct) for anyone to play with.

The aim of the query is to get a list of groups as well as the number of members (a member is a generic term for a person or a company) that have a relationship with the group and its related watchlists.

With the query below I'm getting the correct alert numbers but I'm missing "Empty group" because it doesn't have any members or watchlists. I've tried to make various relationships optional but it ends up getting the count of alerts wrong because it's using watchlists that are related to the group. I've tried countless ways of writing the query but just can't get around the problem.

```
START company=node(233), group=node:node_auto_index("_type:group")
MATCH company-[:OWNS]->group-[?:LINKED_TO]->watchlist-[:WATCHING|APPOINTMENT*1..2]-member<-[:WATCHING]-group
RETURN group, COUNT(DISTINCT(member)) as alerts
ORDER BY group.name
```

Ideally I'd like to make the entire path segment which connects a group to members and then onto watchlists as optional however I can't find out how to do that in the docs or it's just not possible. Is there any other way around this other than doing two queries?

The correct results are that the groups and alerts should be:

```
Big Dot Coms, 1
Big Hitters, 4
Empty group, 0
Old CEOs, 1
```

Comment: I know you said you tried various optional qualifications on relationships, but just to be clear, did you try this? `company-[:OWNS]->group-[?:LINKED_TO]->watchlist-[:WATCHING|APPOINTMENT*1..2]-member, company-[:OWNS]->group-[?:WATCHING]->member`

Comment: I had tried something very similar and it almost works, however the last part returns every member from the watchlist rather than members from both the group and watchlist.

Comment: Would it be possible to create and share a subset of your data on http://console.neo4j.org, that will make it more easy to give assistence.

Comment: I've added it into the question but here it is http://console.neo4j.org/r/vtrcct the starting query isn't the one I placed in the post but it does show the correct number of alerts to be shown for the three visible. It's just the one that doesn't appear which is the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope i understood correctly, but i think this is what you are looking for:

```
START company=node:node_auto_index("name:\"Finance Ltd\""), group=node:node_auto_index("_type:group") 
MATCH company-[:OWNS]->group-[?:WATCHING]->member,group-[?:LINKED_TO]->watchlist 
WITH group, member, watchlist 
MATCH watchlist-[:WATCHING|APPOINTMENT*1..2]-member
RETURN group, count(distinct( member)) 
ORDER BY group.name
```

Basically you can use the `WITH` keyword to gradually build up your query. Firstly get all group<->member pairings including non existing ones. Then optionally match in watchlists and then use a final match to apply your condition and return the results.

Comment: Superb, works exactly as I was hoping. Thanks for clarifying how WITH can help as well.

Comment: i just realized you can combine lines 2-5 into a single query to get significantly shorter execution plan. Although i am personally not sure about the exact performance implications of the WITH keyword and how much is optimized in the db.

Comment: hi @MrDosu, Can you please help me out on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947903/search-list-with-mutual-count-2nd-try?noredirect=1#comment26496571_17947903 thanks

Answer (score 1):

i'm afraid this will never be possible with cypher, because of the traversal pattern :
- you want to count empty groups, this means that there is no node `member`. imagine this simple backtrack: as soon as the search algorithm has no more node to step into, it simply returns one step back. since there is no node `member` the match pattern will never match the whole pattern `company-[:OWNS]->group-[?:LINKED_TO]->watchlist-[:WATCHING|APPOINTMENT*1..2]-member<-[:WATCHING]-group` but only `company-[:OWNS]->group-[?:LINKED_TO]->watchlist`. thus, when the match pattern is not found, there is also no data in the result.

-i suggest to finish the match pattern at the counted nodes, i.e. something like `company-[:OWNS]->group-[?:LINKED_TO]->watchlist-[:WATCHING|APPOINTMENT*1..2]-member`. than you may get the zero in the count result. i tried to play with the console but it seems it does not have any empty group in its data, so i can't create the final query for you.

Comment: Have you tried to use some of the datasets over at http://www.neo4j.org/learn/try @ulkas ?

Comment: @PeterNeubauer the questioner provided a console example, but i couldn't build up the final query. not i couldn;t manualy check the graph  because when i toggle the visualization on on 30nodes my computer goes crazy and i can't manipulate the graph

Comment: There is one empty group, see MrDosu's example for a working query.